# transparent disk backed storage of in-memory data structures

Tags: database

Suppose I were to write a program that stored data in a set of memory based structures (ie, trie, btree, etc.) and provided custom searches on those structures. Are there any Linux based open source frameworks available that would provide for the transparent writing and reading of this data to disk with all of the features of an ACID compliant database? For example, if I were to change the data in memory it would automatically make an atomic change to the data on disk and if I tried to read some data from memory it would automatically load what was needed from disk?

Answer (score 0):

What you look for, is what databases are  design to do , if you need your data in memory , you can set it to stay in memory , in the background you get acid an all other capability , for good open source db for linux  , i will recommend postgresql

Comment: I have been using a database, but I have now run into a query that I fear I can not do efficiently in SQL. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36191659/mysql-check-for-existence-of-value-changes-in-time-range